# How can I find an element based on an attribute value in a namespace?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, attributes

Can anyone suggest an xpath expression to find the following node using the value 'DRIVE_20150917-162707' ?

```
<h4 ext:qtip="DRIVE_20150917-162707"></h4>
```

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: :) sorry not an expert in asking/framing questions - Will do going forward

Comment: It's fine. The point of my post was not to scold you but to encourage you to think carefully about your own question and do your own research so you can better educate yourself. If you did research and tried some things and are still stuck, you can present what you have researched and what you have tried which not only proves that you put some effort into the question but also help us see what you have tried so we can better offer suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is, what have you tried? The following:

```
//h4[@ext:qtip="DRIVE_20150917-162707"]
```

will find all `h4` elements in the document with the value `ext:qtip="DRIVE_20150917-162707"`. As with any namespace, **you must make sure to bind it properly**. If you can't or don't know how to, you can try this:

```
//h4[@*[local-name() = 'qtip'][. ='DRIVE_20150917-162707']]
```

Update: apparently, [Selenium now allows namespace prefixes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1694) and [according to the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/4f5f96d92d12197d85d6faadc0bfb57c6a661c29) (or better, the [current version](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/788f40c0a702a884e1c1fe54a11222d26f0e22ec/javascript/atoms/locators/xpath.js)), they automatically register them against a given prefix. They warn you that it won't work on Android.

Not sure it is the current stable branch, not sure their fix also works with attributes in a namespace, but the problem you mention in the comments below have a different cause (i.e., your document simply does not contain the node). Have a look at [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/firepath/) to try it live in the browser, it should work the same as in Selenium.

### Update, [try the expression above online](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/2e89bdbb8a332f58392d9620c754907b)

Just click the link, I created a little demo. If you still got stuck, then [please give a minimal example that demonstrates the wrong behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

### Update 2, bugs in this approach with Firefox, and a workaround

As per your comments below, where you say it works with `local-name() = 'ext:qtip'`, the expression `local-name()` on an attribute node **returns the prefix and the local name**. This may be the result of [MDN saying that the namespace axis is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/namespace), or the result of [this bug report never implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94270) (see specifically [Michael Sperberg-McQueen's comment #28](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94270#c28)).

It is a strange bug, as the [description of `local-name()` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name) clearly follows the description of the official XPath standard and does not mention incompatibilities.

And I found another strange bug. At least while using Firepath (which uses Firefox XPath underneath), I got the following results on the `html` element of an HTML5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:my="http://other">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body my:other="Yes, in another world!">
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

- `local-name(//*[1])` returned "html", correct
- `name(//*[1])` returned "HTML", **incorrect**
- `namespace-uri(//*[1])` returned " http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", correct, but not in line with what `name()` returned
- `local-name(//body/@*[1])` returned "my:other", **incorrect**
- `name(//body/@*[1])` returned "my:other", correct
- `local-name(//body/@*[1])` returned "" (empty string), **incorrect**

I tried both with and without the namespace declaration in place, it made no difference. This is **clearly a bug in Firefox handling namespaces**, not sure whether it has been reported (couldn't readily found a bug report other than the one already mentioned). Other browsers may do this differently, even correctly, I only tested with Firefox.

Given all these strange behaviors in Firefox, the obvious workaround is to use `@*[local-name() = 'ext:qtip']`. To make this cross-browser friendly and standards-compliant, use:

```
//h4[@*
    [local-name() = 'ext:qtip' 
    or (local-name() = 'qtip' 
        and namespace-uri() = 'fill-in-proper-ns-uri'
    )]
    [.="DRIVE_20150917-162707"]
```

Comment: For the first one: The string '//h4[@ext:qtip='DRIVE_20150917-162707']' contains unresolvable namespaces. Second one : undefined (Tired on firebug)

Comment: @bpk, that's why I said you need to register the namespace. If `undefined` means nothing was found, try it without the second predicate to check if you get back a bunch of `h4` elements to begin with. **Or** provide us with a [mcve], so we can test against a certain input, instead of just guessing ;)

Comment: @bpk, in the absence of a source document, I can't do much more, However. I have updated my answer, perhaps it gives you some pointers. I am, however, positive that the expression matches the requirement in your original question.

Comment: @bpk and another update, where I demonstrate the expression using an online permlink to an xpathtester.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do a minor modification to make this work: local-name() = 'qtip' to local-name() = 'ext:qtip'.

Comment: @bpk that's interesting, that's then either a bug in selenium, or a bug in the browser, because the local name can never contain a colon. Or is the xml not valid and browser fixed it this way?

Comment: @bpk, from [this bug-report it looks like Firefox is the only browser that has no namespace nodes support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94270). While this is not the same as what we are trying to achieve, but that bug may be related. See [comment 28 by C.M. Sperberg-McQueen](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94270#c28), it may help understand the differences in case you run this against different browsers. The patch proposed there has never made it into the main branch...

Comment: @bpk, I investigated a little further and it looks like you hit on a (albeit obscure) bug in Firefox, which doesn't work correctly with the functions `name()`, `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()`. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @bpk, in case you run Selenium with other browsers as well, you want this to be cross-browser compatible. I have added a workaround that works on Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with colon (":") character. 
with css selector you can find

```
h4[ext\:qtip~=DRIVE_20150917-162707]
```

Comment: Yes this one works too. But I will have to go with xpath expression this time.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath mentioned here worked perfectly for me

//*[@*[local-name()='ext:qtip'][.='Buyer']]. This xpath is for